# How to update quiver plot after moving object on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm writing small visualization project which suppose to show vector field around few charged bodies.

My problem is next:
I don't know how to update quiver field after moving circle (charged particle) from primary position.

Link to image, because my reputation is too low. I'm practically new with stackoverflow.

[image]

```
from pylab import *
from scipy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import scipy.constants as const
skr = const.pi*const.epsilon_0*4

class DraggablePoint:
    def __init__(self, p, q0):
        self.q = q0
        self.point = p
        self.c_kruznice = p.center
        self.press = None

    def connect(self):
        self.cidpress = self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_event) 
        self.cidrelease = self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event',self.button_release_event)   
        self.cidmotion = self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.motion_notify_event)  

    def disconnect(self):
        self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)


    def button_press_event(self,event):
        if event.inaxes != self.point.axes:
            return
        contains = self.point.contains(event)[0]
        if not contains: return
        self.press = self.point.center, event.xdata, event.ydata


    def button_release_event(self,event):
        self.press = None
        self.point.figure.canvas.draw()

    def motion_notify_event(self, event):
        if self.press is None: return
        if event.inaxes != self.point.axes: return
        self.point.center, xpress, ypress = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress
        self.point.center = (self.point.center[0]+dx, self.point.center[1]+dy)
        print(self.point.center)
        self.point.figure.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f_s=0.3
    def R(x,y):
        r=np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)+f_s
        return r

    def polje(tela, X, Y):
        Ex = 0
        Ey = 0
        for i in range(len(tela)):
            r=R(tela[i].c_kruznice[0] - X, tela[i].c_kruznice[1] - Y )
            ex = X - tela[i].c_kruznice[0]
            ey = Y - tela[i].c_kruznice[1]
            Ex += (tela[i].q/skr)*(1/(r+f_s)**3)*ex
            Ey += (tela[i].q/skr)*(1/(r+f_s)**3)*ey
        return Ex, Ey

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.05,0.92,0.92])
    ax.set_xlim(-6,6)
    ax.set_ylim(-6,6)
    scale = 0.2
    X,Y=np.mgrid[-5:5:scale, -5:5:scale]

    circles = []
    q=3*const.e
    s=abs(q)
    sx=sqrt(s/np.pi)*1e8*5
    circle2 = patches.Circle((3,0.3), 0.3, fc='r', alpha=0.5, picker=True)
    circle1 = patches.Circle((0.7,0.3), 0.3, fc='r', alpha=0.5, picker=True)
    circle = patches.Circle((-4,0.3), 0.3, fc='b', alpha=0.5, picker=True)
    circles.append(ax.add_patch(circle1))
    circles.append(ax.add_patch(circle))
    circles.append(ax.add_patch(circle2))
    drs = []

    for c in circles:
        print(c.center[0])
        dr = DraggablePoint(c,-1)
        dr.connect()
        drs.append(dr)

    racun=polje(drs, X, Y)
    ax.quiver(X,Y,racun[0],racun[1], color='r',  alpha=0.5)
    ax.quiver(X,Y,racun[0],racun[1], edgecolor='k', facecolor='None', linewidth =.5) 
    plt.show    ()
```

Comment: If you want to animate image, look into matplotlib.animation library. Look into this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687984/plot-a-graph-clear-its-axes-then-plot-a-new-graph/30688207#30688207).

Comment: This is a nice idea but not sure it's simple. As each point is clicked, it triggers its own redraw. The quiver plot depends on the position of all the points so probably shouldn't be redrawn inside a point move event. You could hack something but to do it properly you'd probably need a field class, containing all the points which is the thing bound to mouse events. The field class could then call the point updates you already have while updating the field...

Comment: I, kind of, fixed my problem. [link](http://pastebin.com/1s5aPYuj) 'this' code works, but every time i move some circle i need to click again to refresh quiver field. Also, only one patch is fully movable, others just dissapera when i try to move them, and then redraw again when i 'click-refresh' field. I can say that its usable, buy very buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also new here, so I will try to help as much as I can.

Solution which was logical for me is to give index for your circles. Any time you move a circle your class calls function `button_release_event` as much circles as you have. So, when it comes to last circle (with specific index which you gave it) you just need to erase your plot, and do it all over again (you need to draw circles and field).

Interesting part is that when it is checking circles it will always finish on first one, with index 0. I am not sure why is it happening, but it is great because it is independent of how many circles you have on your graph.

Also, you need to have line `self.c_kruznice = self.point.center[0], self.point.center[1]`, because it will update the center of your point which you dragged so that it can calculate the field. And the crucial part: use `plt.draw()` for drawing field because only than it will update your field after dragging circle. Because `plt.show()` wait for you to finish everything to draw it (that's why it draw when you start your next drag), but `plt.draw()` do it at the time of release.

Edit: You need to clear list `circles` before you re-plot (I edited code).

Here is the code with this idea.

```
from pylab import *
from scipy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import scipy.constants as const

skr = const.pi*const.epsilon_0*4

class DraggablePoint:
    global Polje
    def __init__(self, p, q0, ind):
        self.q = q0
        self.point = p
        self.c_kruznice = p.center
        self.press = None
        self.indeks = ind

    def connect(self):
        self.cidpress = self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_event)
        self.cidrelease = self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event',self.button_release_event)  
        self.cidmotion = self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.motion_notify_event)  

    def disconnect(self):
        self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)

    def button_press_event(self,event):
        if event.inaxes != self.point.axes:
            return
        contains = self.point.contains(event)[0]
        if not contains: return
        self.press = self.point.center, event.xdata, event.ydata

    def button_release_event(self,event):
        self.press = None
        self.point.figure.canvas.draw()
        # This is the part which will erase field
        # and draw for us new one
        self.c_kruznice = self.point.center[0], self.point.center[1]
        if self.indeks == 0:
            racun = polje(drs, X, Y)
            ax.cla()
            circles = []
            circles.append(ax.add_patch(circle1))
            circles.append(ax.add_patch(circle))
            circles.append(ax.add_patch(circle2))
            circles.append(ax.add_patch(circle3))
            ax.quiver(X,Y,racun[0],racun[1], color='r',  alpha=0.5)
            ax.quiver(X,Y,racun[0],racun[1], edgecolor='k', facecolor='None', linewidth =.5)
            plt.draw()

    def motion_notify_event(self, event):
        if self.press is None: return
        if event.inaxes != self.point.axes: returnO
        self.point.center, xpress, ypress = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress
        self.point.center = (self.point.center[0]+dx, self.point.center[1]+dy)
        self.point.figure.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f_s=0.3
    def R(x,y):
        r=np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)+f_s
        return r

    def polje(tela, X, Y):
        Ex = 0
        Ey = 0
        for i in range(len(tela)):
            r = R(tela[i].c_kruznice[0] - X, tela[i].c_kruznice[1] - Y )
            ex = X - tela[i].c_kruznice[0]
            ey = Y - tela[i].c_kruznice[1]
            Ex += (tela[i].q/skr)*(1/(r+f_s)**3)*ex
            Ey += (tela[i].q/skr)*(1/(r+f_s)**3)*ey
        return Ex, Ey


    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.05,0.92,0.92])
    ax.set_xlim(-6,6)
    ax.set_ylim(-6,6)
    scale = 0.2
    X,Y=np.mgrid[-5:5:scale, -5:5:scale]

    circles = []
    q=3*const.e
    s=abs(q)
    sx=sqrt(s/np.pi)*1e8*5
    circle2 = patches.Circle((2,3), 0.3, fc='r', alpha=0.5, picker=True)
    circle1 = patches.Circle((2,-3), 0.3, fc='r', alpha=0.5, picker=True)
    circle = patches.Circle((-2,3), 0.3, fc='b', alpha=0.5, picker=True)
    circle3 = patches.Circle((-2,-3), 0.3, fc = 'b', alpha = 0.5, picker = True )
    circles.append(ax.add_patch(circle1))
    circles.append(ax.add_patch(circle))
    circles.append(ax.add_patch(circle2))
    circles.append(ax.add_patch(circle3))
    drs = []

    i = 0
    q = [-1, 1, -1, 1]
    for c in circles:
        dr = DraggablePoint(c, q[i], i)
        dr.connect()
        drs.append(dr)
        i += 1

    racun = polje(drs, X, Y)
    ax.quiver(X,Y,racun[0],racun[1], color='r',  alpha=0.5)
    ax.quiver(X,Y,racun[0],racun[1], edgecolor='k', facecolor='None', linewidth =.5)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This is actually what i wanted. After this, i updated to N body visualization in few seconds.